# compiling the scipsuit (linux)

Tags: scip

I downloaded the scipsuit and tried to `make' it. Here is the error I get. Any idea how to  resolve it?

```
make[2]: Leaving directory `/shared/shelley/khashab2/SCIP/extracted/zimpl-3.3.2'
-> compiling obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/mpsinput.o
In file included from src/basevectors.h:24,
                 from src/svector.h:25,
                 from src/slinsolver.h:27,
                 from src/clufactor.h:23,
                 from src/clufactor.cpp:19:
src/rational.h:119: error: only declarations of constructors can be ‘explicit’
src/rational.h:122: error: only declarations of constructors can be ‘explicit’
In file included from src/basevectors.h:24,
                 from src/spxlpbase.h:28,
                 from src/spxlp.h:24,
                 from src/spxsolver.h:30,
                 from src/spxratiotester.h:26,
                 from src/enter.cpp:23:
src/rational.h:119: error: only declarations of constructors can be ‘explicit’
src/rational.h:122: error: only declarations of constructors can be ‘explicit’
make[3]: *** [obj/O.linux.x86_64.gnu.opt/lib/clufactor.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from src/basevectors.h:24,
                 from src/spxlpbase.h:28,
                 from src/spxlp.h:24,
                 from src/spxsolver.h:30,
                 from src/changesoplex.cpp:22:
src/rational.h:119: error: only declarations of 
...
```

Here is the GCC version:

```
[khashab2@austen extracted]$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-11)
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of GCC is too old. You may either use a newer version (recommended), or try compiling with `LEGACY=true`. This will disable the rational solving mode.